# Combine the multiple API responses in to one JSON object C#

Tags: c#, rest, api, sharepoint

I am calling the Sharepoint REST API from the C# application multiple times becaues of pagination and it cannot return more the 5000 records at a time. I am calling the API through the loop like

```
     for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i = i + 5000)
            {
                SP_StrainCodes = "GetByTitle('S%20Codes')/items?$skiptoken=Paged=TRUE%26p_ID=" + i + "&$top=1";
                core_URL = BaseURL_SP + SP_StrainCodes;

                using (var client_sharePoint = new HttpClient(handler))
                {
                    var response = client_sharePoint.GetAsync(core_URL).Result;
                    var responsedata = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    returnObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SharepointDTO.RootObject>(responsedata);

                    if (returnObj.d.Next == null)
                        continue;
               }
            }
            return returnObj;
        }
```

How do I combine the the returnObj from 1st call and the 2nd Call and return as one Object

Comment: Why you don't create a List of RootObject and add each result set to it ?
I think it's not possible to merge the results like you want in simple way.

Comment: @MojtabaTajik How would I do that? Cant we use any Merge or Concat functions. I tried thoughit didnt work.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this :

```
  List<SharepointDTO.RootObject> results = new List<SharepointDTO.RootObject>();

  for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i = i + 5000)
            {
                SP_StrainCodes = "GetByTitle('S%20Codes')/items?$skiptoken=Paged=TRUE%26p_ID=" + i + "&$top=1";
                core_URL = BaseURL_SP + SP_StrainCodes;

                using (var client_sharePoint = new HttpClient(handler))
                {
                    var response = client_sharePoint.GetAsync(core_URL).Result;
                    var responsedata = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    returnObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SharepointDTO.RootObject>(responsedata);

                    if (returnObj.d.Next == null)
                        continue;
               }

               results.Add(returnObj);
            }
            return results;
```